# Using a Spring RowMapper in order to populate a field of type Collection from a JDBC resultset

Tags: join, jdbc, inner-join, spring-jdbc

I am trying to map a JDBC `ResultSet` to a POJO using a Spring `RowMapper` as follows:

```
public class AdvertisementMapper implements RowMapper<Advertisement> {

    @Override
    public Advertisement mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Advertisement advertisement = new Advertisement();
        advertisement.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
        advertisement.setAdvertisementType(AdvertisementType.valueOf(rs.getString("advertisement_type")));
        advertisement.setNeed(Need.valueOf(rs.getString("need")));
        advertisement.setChildcareWorkerType(ChildcareWorkerType.valueOf(rs.getString("childcare_worker_type")));
        advertisement.setChildcareTypes(null);//COLLECTION!
        advertisement.setDayToTimeSlots(null);//COLLECTION!
        advertisement.setLanguages(null);//COLLECTION!
        advertisement.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
        advertisement.setCreationDate(rs.getDate("creation_date"));
        advertisement.setExpirationDate(rs.getDate("expiration_date"));
        advertisement.setActive(rs.getBoolean("active"));
        advertisement.setValidated(rs.getBoolean("validated"));
        Member member = new Member();
        member.setId(rs.getLong("memberId"));
        advertisement.setMember(member);
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setLat(rs.getDouble("addressLat"));
        address.setLon(rs.getDouble("addressLon"));
        advertisement.setAddress(address);
        advertisement.setFirstAidTraining(Choice.valueOf(rs.getString("first_aid_training")));
        advertisement.setGiveBath(Choice.valueOf(rs.getString("give_bath")));
        advertisement.setPrepareMeals(Choice.valueOf(rs.getString("prepare_meals")));
        advertisement.setHelpWithHomework(Choice.valueOf(rs.getString("help_with_homework")));
        advertisement.setCleaningIroning(Choice.valueOf(rs.getString("cleaning_ironing")));
        advertisement.setVersion(rs.getInt("version"));
        return advertisement;
    }
}
```

I have an issue with three fields which are of type: `java.util.Set` (I have added a `//COLLECTION!` comment to them in the java code above.)

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM 
advertisement a, 
advertisement_childcare_types act, 
advertisement_day_to_time_slots adtts, 
day_to_time_slot dtts,
advertisement_languages al,
language l
WHERE 
a.id = act.advertisement AND
a.id = adtts.advertisement AND
adtts.day_to_time_slots = dtts.id AND
a.id = al.advertisement AND
al.languages = l.id
```

I am not sure how to populate the collection/`java.util.Set` fields from the `ResultSet`...

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have a one-to-one mapping from rows in your resultset to `Advertisement` instances, you won't be able to do this with a `RowMapper`. You will need to use a [RowCallbackHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html) or a [ResultSetExtractor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html)`<List<Advertisement>>`. The advantage to the `RowCallbackHandler` is that you don't need to deal with calling `next()`.

Here is a non-threadsafe, not super-efficient, but clear implementation:

```
class AdvertisementRowcallbackHandler implements RowCallbackHandler {

  Map<Long, Advertisement> results = new HashMap<>();

  @Override
  void processRow(ResultSet rs) SQLException {
    long id = rs.getLong("id");
    Advertisement advertisement = new Advertisement();
    advertisement.setChildcareWorkerTypes(new HashSet<>());
    results.putIfAbsent(id, advertisement);
    advertisement = results.get(id);
    // You could be smart about only setting these if it was absent in the map
    advertisement.setId(id);
    advertisement.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
    advertisement.getChildcareWorkerTypes().add(rs.getString("worker_type"));
    // ...
  }
}
```

And then you would get the result with `new ArrayList<>(handler.results.values())`.